# Is there an error when make component with class and use tag html after return

Tags: reactjs

```
class Timer extends Component{
  render(){
    return{
      <h1> </h1>
    }
  }
}
```

Parsing error: Unexpected token , when i use tag html in class component
ReactJS

Comment: Set babel to use `@babel/preset-react` so JSXs will be transpiled correctly.

Comment: you have to use return within brackets return(<h1> </h1>)

Comment: @Malith i try to use bracket stil parsing error

Answer (score 1):

After your return you use curly braces, they should be just `return (...)`. And make sure to import react when using jsx